# unity how to make an animation reverse mid way through

Tags: c#, unity, animation

I have a animation of several parts moving (think bridge) and would like the animation to reverse mid way through if a certain condition is modified (function call). I have the `Animation` and the `AnimationClip` which are added via a script.

Currently this is the code:

```
Animation anim;
public AnimationClip Open; 
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    anim.AddClip (Open, "Open");
    anim.Play ("Open");

}
void Update(){
    Debug.Log ("update");
    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) {
        rev ();
        Debug.Log("reversing");
    }
}
void rev(){
    anim.Rewind()

}
```

However `anim.Rewind()` doesn't do what I want it to do it moves the animation back the the first frame rather then slowly move the animation backwards. I know there are some tricks involving the time or by changing the speed but I cannot figure those out either.

Comment: I'm not really that familiar with Unity, but have you tried setting the animation speed to a negative value?

Comment: I looked for that but anim.speed() doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I don't think it's a function, rather a property. See [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/playing-animation-backwards.15071/).